# Pass object to plyr's rename()

Tags: r, plyr

Is it possible to pass variables to `rename`? For instance:

```
fake1 <- rename(mtcars, replace=c("mpg"="new.mpg"))
```

works just fine. However,

```
old_name <- "mpg"
fake2 <- rename(mtcars, replace=c(old_name="new.mpg"))
```

fails to map `old_name` to `"mpg"`, instead gives the warning `The following`from`values were not present in`x`: old_name`.

Obviously I can rename using something like

```
names(mtcars)[names(mtcars)==old_name] <- "new.mpg"
```

but `rename` is so convenient (also I don't quite understand why the variable wouldn't be interpreted as the string it represents).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
rename(mtcars,replace = setNames("new.mpg",old_name))
```